# PHP get a Date with a specific offset

Tags: php

Here's my problem.  I need to get the current date `Y-m-d` in Central time (UTC-0600), year around ignoring Daylight Savings Time.

Currently one option I found was

```
$date = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('Canada/Saskatchewan'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

My only problem with this being that if ever that timezone wanted to respect Daylight Savings Time, I'd be off.  This works also, but only on something like php 5.5.18+:

```
$date = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('-0600'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

My current server I believe would support `new \DateTimeZone('-0600')` but I'm not 100% on if this is the most appropriate way to handle the situation.

What would you recommend be the most accurate way to get the date for UTC-0600 in PHP?  Or should I just stick with what I got right now?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried the function `gmdate` ?

Comment: @VasilShaddix I'm not sure how `gmdate()` will help in this situation as it always returns a date in GMT.  And I need a date in Central Standard Time.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, you want to get the `Y-d-m` of a timezone and respect the daylight saving changes ?

Comment: @VasilShaddix Sorry if it wasn't clear.  I need to get the date for CST (UTC-0600) all year long, ignoring Daylight Savings Time.  And I just want to confirm that the method I'm using above is the best, or if there is a better way to handle this.  The problem is an API I'm communicating with requires I send an AuthDate, that AuthDate cannot be in the future.  Currently I'm using `America/Chicago` for the timezone, but come Daylight Savings Time on sunday, all requests will be invalid from 23:00-00:00.  So I'm looking for a better timezone to use.